# Force the browser to save downloaded file in a specific location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, download

My project is an `Asp.Net MVC4` web application.

Currently it has a method to generate a text file and send it to the client's browser for download.

I need to modify it to force the browser to save the file in a custom (pre-defined) location on the client's computer.

Comment: Let me know if there's a browser that supports this, and I'll be sure to never use that browser.

Comment: Fortunately you cant!

Comment: I know that. I'm working on a team that developing a enterprise application for our company. One of our developer needs this to be done. I asked here if there would be a chance to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be possible as it would introduce a severe security problem.  A user has to decide where the file will be saved.

You can only specify a location on a server to which you have access to.

If its an internal site, then you could setup the server to save the file to a network location and return that path to the user..

If you want to show a save as, add this to your ActionResult to indicate a file download:

```
Response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie("fileDownload", "true") { Path = "/" });
return myFileStreamResult
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I force the browser to show `Save As` dialog?

Comment: Yes. This is not a public site.
Can I save the file in another server and send the path?

Comment: you can save it to a shared network location if required yes then send the path and display a link to the location which the user can then click

Answer (score 0):

I needed to download and sort files into a rigidly defined directory structure on the client machine with no possibility of user mistakes. Ideally it would be completely automatic. I couldn't make it fully automatic, but in Chrome in Windows, I eliminated the possibility of typing mistakes with:

```
<a class="aDownload" href="file.txt" download="CTRL+V for suggested path/file">Download</a>
<textarea id="textareaClipboard"></textarea>
```

Using jQuery to listen for a click of the link, I call a function to generate the desired path and final file name, put it in the textarea, and transfer this to the clipboard using

```
jQuery('#textareaClipboard').select();
document.execCommand('copy' ,null ,null);
```

The Save As dialog pops up with "CTRL+V for suggested path/file" in the file name field. Follow the suggestion to paste the generated file name into this field, and hit Enter.

It requires a minimal amount of user action to ensure the file goes to the right directory with the right name, and the user can always reject the suggestion.

Comment: If that works, wouldn't programmatically setting the download attribute to the desired filename work too?

Comment: The browser seems to change some characters, including \ and :, to dashes before the the dialog pops up.

Answer (score -1):

Your web application only can sending file to your client. its imposible to force download and save to spesific location, because download and save to privilege is belongs to client browser.

if user not defined default download location, it will prompt save to when download something, then if user already defined default download location. it will download automatically and save to default location.

so i think you have a little misconception with your web logic :D